# How do I close an existing Tkinter window when a new Tkinter window opens?

Tags: python, database, sqlite, tkinter

I'm currently working on a school project where I have to develop a database system. I have my login screen functioning correctly. When the user logs in, the main menu screen opens, however, the login screen remains open when I would ideally like it to close. My code is attached below with an image of the screens.

```
class Toplevel1:

def UserLogin(self): #Login function for staff members
    while True:
        staffid = self.Entry1.get();
        password = self.Entry2.get();
        with sqlite3.connect("LeeOpt.db") as db: #Connects to the database file
            cursor = db.cursor()
            find_user = ('SELECT * FROM Login WHERE StaffID = ? AND Password = ?')
            cursor.execute(find_user, [(staffid),(password)])
            results = cursor.fetchall()
            
            if results:
                for i in results:
                    MainMenu.create_Toplevel1(root)
                    return("exit")
            else:
                tkinter.messagebox.showerror("Error", "The staffID or password is incorrect, please try again.")
                
                time.sleep(1)
                return("exit")
```

[image]

Comment: Have you read through the documentation? The `destroy` method is documented.

Comment: @BryanOakley I tried using the quit method but the entire program stopped. I'll try the destroy method now.

Comment: Please don't post code in the comments. You can [edit]  your question to include additional details.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use the .destroy method on the tkinter window for the log in screen to destroy it once logged in (Do this just after you open the main menu window). [Link to destroy method on tutorials point](https://www.tutorialspoint.com/destroy-method-in-tkinter-python)